# Verification of encryption for ElGamal cryptosystem

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, elgamal-encryption

Suppose Alice wants to convince Bob that ciphertext **c = (a, b) = (g<sup>r</sup>, m*h<sup>r</sup>)** is some properly encrypted plaintext (not just random numbers). Obviously she can use zk-proof of discrete logarithm knowledge for the first part of the ciphertext (**a = g<sup>r</sup>**). But what can she do with **b**-part?

One of my ideas: if **m** belongs to subgroup **G** (with a generator **g**) than we should prove that **b** belongs to **G**. But it's just a new problem.

Alice can also use exponential ElGamal (**c = (g<sup>r</sup>, g<sup>m</sup> * h<sup>r</sup>)**) if it makes things easier.

Comment: One can use the same response for $r$ (part of the proof) for two proofs about both parts of the ciphertext. "Some $r$ exists" seems somewhat general; practical cases may include something like "and $m$ is either $g$ or $1$" (0 or 1 for the second variant). Will you refine your "properly" condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, an ElGamal ciphertext $(a,b)$ is *"valid"* iff $(a,b) \in G^2$,  because for any message $m\in G$ and any $\mathsf{pk}\in G$, the encryption of $m$ will be in $G^2$, because for any $r$, $(g^r,\mathsf{pk}^r\cdot m)\in G^2$, and any $(a,b)$ chosen in $G^2$ can be correctly decrypted by any secret key by computing $m=\frac{b}{a^\mathsf{sk}}$. The proof of knowledge of the random coin $r$ is sufficient to show that you know *how the ciphertext was produced*.

I do not know if that answers your problem.